# Add Tuple to Map?

Tags: scala

Using Scala 2.11.8, I can append a `key - value` pair to a Map via:

```
scala> Map( (1 -> 1) ) + (2 -> 2)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

But how can I use tuple as the `+`'s argument?

```
scala> Map( (1 -> 1) ) + (2, 2)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: (Int, ?)
       Map( (1 -> 1) ) + (2, 2)
                          ^
```

Nor does this work:

```
scala> Map( (1, 1) ) + (2, 2)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: (Int, ?)
       Map( (1, 1) ) + (2, 2)
                        ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: (Int, ?)
       Map( (1, 1) ) + (2, 2)
                           ^
```

[Map#+](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@+(kv:(A,B)):scala.collection.Map[A,B])'s signature is:

`+(kv: (A, B)): Map[A, B]`, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

**EDIT**

```
scala> Map( (1,1) ).+( (2, 2) )
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

works, but why doesn't the above?

Comment: `Map((1 -> 1)) + ((2, 2))`

Comment: So two parentheses to `((2, 2))` are needed since the first is pass args to `(`; and the second `(` begins the tuple?

Comment: Post for answer, Jesper, to take credit?

Comment: This is actually a big mystery for many Scala developers. Very few notice that `1 -> 2` is equivalent to `(1, 2)`. Things like this need to be added to Scala gotcha's article somewhere.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh `->` is a method that takes two values and returns a tuple, and with `1 -> 2` you're calling the method with infix syntax.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this somewhere..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Scala, any binary operation (`*`,`+`, etc.) is actually a method of the class of the first element in the operation.

So, for example, `2 * 2` is equivalent to `2.*(2)`, because `*` is just a method of the class `Int`.

What is happening when you type `Map( (1 -> 1) ) + (2, 2)` is that Scala recognizes that you are using the `+` method of the `Map` class. However it thinks that you are trying to pass multiple values to this method because it defaults to interpreting the opening paren as the beginning of a parameter list (this is a (reasonable) design decision).

The way you resolve this is to wrap the tuple in another pair of parens or to use the `->` syntax (with parens, because operator precedence).

```
scala> Map( (1 -> 1) ) + ((2, 2))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)

scala> Map( (1 -> 1) ) + (2 -> 2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```